# finding the distance between one camera and one object, knowing the dimensions of the object using opencv

Tags: opencv

I am working on robotic arm, and trying to find the distance between one camera and one object, knowing the dimensions of the object using open CV.

I not sure how to do it.

I tried using `visual servoing` method but not succeeded.

Any help will be nice

Comment: Did you identify the object by the camera? Frankly that is orders of magnitude harder; if you solved that problem, surely finding the distance would be a piece of cake for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution for starting:

1.) First, you have to calibrate your camera to receive the `C` matrix. For example:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

2.) Then you have to identify on the image two points of the object which distance is known. Let's be these points `P1(X1, Y1, Z1)` and `P2(X2, Y2, Z2)` in the 3D space and `p1(x1, y1)` and `p2(x2, y2)` in 2D image plane. Certainly `P1` and `P2` are not known, only their pairs on the image (`p1` and `p2`) and their distance `D`.

3.) Next, if you know the camera calibration matrix `C`, you have two equations:

`p1 = C * P1` and `p2 = C * P2`

Then: `C^-1 * p1 = P1'` and `C^-1 * p2 = P2'` where `P1' = (X1 / Z1, Y1 / Z1, 1)` and `P2' = (X2 / Z2, Y2 / Z2, 1)`. This means that `C^-1 * p1` returns the 3D coordinates of the point belong the `Z1 = 1` distance.

But the exact distance is not 1 but it is `Z1` and `Z2`. Now, let's suppose that `Z1 == Z2 == Z` and we are looking for the distance `Z`.

This follows that `Z * C^-1 * p1 = P1` and `Z * C^-1 * p2 = P2`.

Next `(Z * C^-1 * p1) - (Z * C^-1 * p2) = P1 - P2`, and

`Z * ((C^-1 * p1) - C^-1 * p2)) = P1 - P2`, and

`Z^2 * ((C^-1 * p1) - C^-1 * p2))^2 = (P1 - P2)^2 = D^2`

Now, `C`, `p1`, `p2` and `D` are known, only `Z` is the unknown variable in the last equation.

Certainly, this is only a basic solution and uses the assumpion that the distances of the object's points are very similar, but it can work.